# Embedded chart legend disappear when modifying a chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I a script that modifies a spreadsheet embedded chart title and range as follows:

```
var title = chart.getOptions().get('title');
var legend = chart.getOptions().get('legend');
var ranges = chart.getRanges();

var builder = chart.modify();

for (var j in ranges) {
  var range = ranges[j];
  // rangeShouldExpand is defined later.
  var newRange = getTableNewRange_(range);
  if (newRange !== null) {
    // Removes the old range and substitutes with new one.
    builder.removeRange(range);
    builder.addRange(newRange);
  }
}

// Update title
builder.setOption('title', newTitle);
// as Google may have a bug of disappearing legends on updating chart then reset the legend as before
builder.setOption('legend', legend);

sheet.updateChart(builder.build());
```

For some reasons the legend kept disappearing when performing this. I therefore added a code to get the chart legend option and reset it but it is still happening. Can someone tell me what am i doing wrong that causes the legend to disappear?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I have filed a bug report and it appears to be resolved as of January 21st.